# Are track lighting systems standardized/universal?

Tags: lighting

Our business has track for track lighting, but the previous tenants took the fixtures with them when they moved out.  I want to buy and install some pendant and spotlight track lights, but I'm not sure whether I have to look for models compatible with a certain standard, or if I possibly even have to stick to the same brand as the track manufacturer.

I think the manufacturer of the track is Juno, but I'll have to double-check whether it's line-voltage or low-voltage.  Once I figure out the voltage, should I be able to buy any track lights, or are they all standardized/universal so that I can buy any fixture of the proper voltage?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.  First as you have mentioned there is line and low voltage.  If you are not sure what to choose from pick line voltage - you can always put it on a dimmer to get what you need.  The low voltage tracks in my opinion are junk because they only allow a certain amount of light, and the transformers go out or hummmm after a while.  That is just my opinion on this - people will say you can find more selection of light bulbs with low voltage and there are special circumstances where this is right but you can order a lot of stuff easy on the internet now.

OK back to your main question.  No again.  In the US there are three main types.  See the picture below.

[image]

Get a ladder and take a look at your track or take a picture on your phone.  The Juno tracks I have seen have been j-style but you need to look because they are a huge maker and I am sure they have made each style.

Comment: You may be able to take an end cap off to get a better view of the track.